# How to cut short a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile

I have a large world map in a shapefile from which I need to crop a smaller region. I am planning to use in in java based simulation. How to do that?

I am completely new to GIS world so can anyone recommend a decent tutorial on basic manipulations to help me understand what is actually going on?

Comment: Please include the software you are working with (e.g. ArcGIS, QGIS, etc).  Thanks.

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is *clip* or *extract* and as @Aaron indicated the methods for achieving this differs based on what software package you are using. Most decent (or at least recent) GIS packages don't require clipping to a specific region, instead they use something called *spatial indexing* to find which features to display.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you are new to GIS, I'm asuming that you would also need help selecting a software which can do this for you.

You can do this with GDAL's [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility.

You should have a look at the `clipsrc` parameter. The documentation for this parameter states:

> -clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|WKT|datasource|spat_extent:
>
> ```
>  (starting with GDAL 1.7.0) clip geometries to the 
>  specified bounding box (expressed in source SRS), WKT geometry (POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON),
>  from a datasource or to the spatial extent of the -spat option 
>  if you use the spat_extent keyword. When specifying a datasource, you will generally want to use it in
>  combination of the -clipsrclayer, -clipsrcwhere or -clipsrcsql options
> ```

So you can pass it either a polygon shapefile to which you want to clip, or you can pass in the bounding box in `[xmin ymin xmax ymax]` format.

For example, if your input shapefile is `input.shp`, and you clipping shapefile is `clipping_polygon.shp`, you can use the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc clipping_polygon.shp output.shp input.shp
```

Or if you want to clip to a particular extent, say `[65, 5, 105, 45]`, you could use the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc 65 5 105 45 output.shp input.shp
```